# Using The @ symbol for a Directory so two backslashes aren't needed

Tags: c#, parsing, backslash

this seems very simple but upon research I cannot find out how to use the @ sign in a directory to prevent it from having to be to backslashes.

An example is of

```
DirectoryInfo folderInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
```

But In my Application The directory will be dynamic so I cannot do this:

```
DirectoryInfo folderInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@Globals.directoryRoute);
```

So I was wondering what is the correct way to put the `@` symbol before the string.

`Globals.directoryRoute` is set as `C:\` but the user can change this input so I was hoping instead of having to parse out every double backslash I can use this to make it so only one backslash is needed.

Would this be an effective way of doing it or should I just parse out every second backslash?

Comment: Just to clarify, the `@` escape applies to source code literals only. It is not needed for strings coming from elsewhere (config files, database, etc.).

Comment: Post how you set Globals.directoryRoot

Comment: @500-InternalServerError You're right, For Some Reason I was Assuming I had to Parse The Data In As A Double BackSlash. I guess I wasn't paying much attention, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @ prefix is a tool to tell the compiler to not take the backslash as an escape character within the following string. If the string is entered at runtime, you don't need to worry about that. So you can just use the content of `Globals.directoryRoute` as it is.

Answer (score 2):

The double backslashes are only needed for string literals in your code. In memory, only a single backslash is stored in the string, so no `@` symbol is needed when dealing with strings that are already in memory. Similarly, user input does not need the double backslashes, since it is not interpreted in the same manner as source code. For instance, if you have a text box called `txtPath`, the user can simply type `C:\some\path`, not `C:\\some\\path` as you would normally need to do in source code. When you read the value of that text box in code, you can just use:
`string path = txtPath.Text;`
This will be the same as if you had the following code:
`string path = @"C:\some\path";`
or, equivalently:
`string path = "C:\\some\\path";`